# R version and ncdf compatibility for Windows

Tags: r

I would like to install the `ncdf` package in `R` for Windows but this package is not available for `R 3.5.1` anymore. Does anyone know which version of `R` and `ncdf` are compatible in order to download and install it?

[ncdf versions](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ncdf/?fbclid=IwAR3xmoeJBGWiPSAu8R4yJg_YhZCa7XOaID4T837M-qJHOjcdD4vwlilCn2M)

[R versions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/?fbclid=IwAR3ZQe8xoqWQodOd4zK40qXL_lriDcJf3BfJ6YXlTcSiNdwnvp7g-5-HHx4)

I am trying with:

1:`devtools::install_github("cran/ncdf")`

2:`remotes::install_local("path/archive.tar.gz")`

after downloading the relative ncdf.tar.gz

NOTE: My final goal is to install `clim.pact` but this is based on the installation of `ncdf`

Comment: why not using ncdf4?

Comment: Because clim.pact that I want to install later works with ncdf

Comment: archived on 2016/01/01  I guess you can use the r version older than that, see here https://cran.r-project.org/

Comment: I have tried ncdf_1.6.9.tar.gz 2015-11-29 22:00 with R 3.2.2 (August, 2015) but not working

Comment: hummm :s what do you need in the package clim.pact? Can't you update the function you need with ncdf4 for example?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187261/discussion-between-lemairev-and-firmo23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the `3.0.3` version of R and installed the `1.6.8` version of `ncdf`, available here:
 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/. 
It works.

Comment: Which installation method did you follow since remotes is not available for R 3.0.3?

Comment: @firmo23 I downloaded the zip file from the link above and then installed it using "Install packages from local files"

Comment: Im going to accept your answer since it answers the original Q but clim.pact is not available for this r version

Comment: @firmo23 If you only need `cdfextract.R` and `retrieve.nc.R`, you can download these functions from: https://github.com/cran/clim.pact/tree/master/R